# Как написать SQL запрос с помощью регулярного выражения для поиска строк содержащих перед символом @ 4 цифры?

Tags: sql, sql-server

я использую MSSQL и пытаюсь найти все строки в которых есть 4 цифры перед символом @ в MSSQl
Мой запрос выглядит следующим образом

```
SELECT * FROM Contact WHERE Email LIKE '%\d{4}@%' ESCAPE '\'
```

Он отлично отрабатывает в конструкторах regexp и в коде Js, но в SQL он не отдает ничего
Вот строка , которую я пытаюсь найти **a.bakerd1234@ac.com**
Да можно воспользоваться
`SELECT * FROM Contact WHERE Email LIKE '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]@%' ESCAPE '\'`
но это я бы хотел понять, как исправить мое регулярное выражение

Comment: Регулярки Sql Server очень [ограничены](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#arguments) и не содержат метасимвола `d` для цифр. Придётся использовать `[0-9]`.

Comment: Как вариант, можно сделать CLF function с регулярками дотнета.

Comment: Привет, MsSql работает с символами вроде \d, если указать ESCAPE , но с {4} о не хочет работать, простите , что не уточнил изначально

Answer (score 1):

Проверил на MS SQL, так работает

```
SELECT * FROM 
(   
    SELECT * FROM 
    (
        VALUES
            (1, 'email.asd@ya.ru'),
            (2, 'something1234@new.ru'),
            (3, '@ya.ru'),
            (4, 'asdasd'),
            (5, '_asdasdasd@mail.ru'),
            (6, 'asd_asdas@mail.ru'),
            (7, '.asdasd@mail.ru'),
            (8, '007asd@email.com'),
            (9, 'a.bakerd1234@ac.com'),
            (10, 'a.bakerd1234ac.com')
    ) AS emails(id, email)
) SQ
WHERE SQ.email LIKE ('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%@%')
```

Comment: Ааа, пардон, сразу не увидел, что Вы хотите именно со своим регулярным выражением.

Comment: что-то с cte бы смотрелось компактнее, кажется